# Issue in exposing 'Link' of ReactRouter using webpack Shimming ProvidePlugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

REF: [Webpack ProvidePlugin plugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules#plugin-provideplugin)

We are using webpack shimming ProvidePlugin to expose globally used modules like underscore, React, ReactRouter but when it comes to "Link" which is in hierarchy of ReactRouter.Link we are not finding any solution to expose Link directly using ProvidePlugin.

Though we exposed ReactRouter using provide plugin and able to do ReactRouter.Link in the application.